# How To Configure Custom CookieGenerator Spring to override the cookie path

Tags: java, session, tomcat

I am unable to configure custom CookieGenerator in Spring.
The requirement is very simple, I need to set the path of cookie to root "/" but didn't find any configuration settings. Since my war file is portal.war and bydefault spring is setting path=/portal which I want to change.
I searched on google but non of the option is working coz most of the solution as referring to older version of spring.

Here is what I have tried : 
Created MyCookieGenerator :

```
public class MyCookieGenerator extends CookieGenerator {
        @Override
        public String getCookiePath() {
            return DEFAULT_COOKIE_PATH;
        }

        @Override
        public void setCookiePath(String cookiePath) {
            super.setCookiePath(DEFAULT_COOKIE_PATH);
        }

}
```

And added following bean in context.xml

```
< bean id="cookieGenerator" class="com.test.web.util.MyCookieGenerator" />
```

but this is not working. It seems to be some small configuration but I am unable to find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

CookieGenerator has a default property DEFAULT_COOKIE_PATH, which shows to the root:

```
public class CookieGenerator {
    public static final String DEFAULT_COOKIE_PATH = "/";
...
}
```

If in xml Spring declaration, you declare to use it, then your cookie path will be set to root

```
<bean id="cookieGenerator" class="com.test.web.util.MyCookieGenerator" />
    <property name="useDefaultPath" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

Hope it helps.
Best regards!